Нестандартный вопрос по теме числительных (составные числительные на "один")

Как известно из правила Розенталя, литературной формой будет  сочетание зачислить на курс тридцать два студента (форма В.п. для одуш. сущ.), а разговорной — тридцать двух студентов.
О категории одушевленности для СОСТАВНЫХ 
числительных: Розенталь §153. Пункт 4. При 
литературной форме доставить двадцать два 
пассажира (в конструкциях с составными 
числительными, оканчивающимися на два, три, 
четыре, винительный падеж СОХРАНЯЕТ форму 
именительного независимо от категории 
одушевленности) существует разговорная форма 
доставить двадцать двух пассажиров.


Но почему правило не действует для составных числительных на "один": зачислить на курс тридцать одного студента (форма Р.п. для одуш. сущ.).


P. S. Смысл вопроса в следующем.
По своим грамматическим свойствам слово  один выделяется среди других числительных. Но как эти свойства позволяют ему "уклониться" от правила  для составных числительных.
Кстати, можно спросить: насколько обоснованным является  это правило, то есть из чего оно следует?   Но это уже другой вопрос)).
Я очень рассчитываю  не только на ваше знание темы, но и на вашу логику при ответах.
